# Can not start rails server after changing gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just started the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl. I am currently trying to get the exact same gems versions (listing 1.5 in the book) he uses to avoid future problems. I managed to run bundle update and bundle install with no problems but when I try to start the server by rails server I get error you will see below.

The only main difference I can spot between his dev environment and mine is that I use rbenv and set the local ruby version for the project to 2.0.0-p353, and he uses RVM with ruby version 2.0.0. Could this be causing the problem? I can't find a ruby 2.0.0 version (without any -p...) on rbenv.

Thank you for your help!!

```
  => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x007ff71196dee8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/Desktop/rails_projects/first_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /Users/eduardopoleo/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: look at your `/config/environments/development.rb` file `configure` should probably by `config` in this file.

Comment: Make sure your `FirstApp::Application` in `config/application.rb` inherits from `Rails::Application`